# How to make sum of each value of list

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, integer, logic

```
# List_values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
# Example :
# 21 = 1+2+3+4+5+6
# 27 = 2+3+4+5+6+7
# 33 = 3+4+5+6+7+8
# 39 = 4+5+6+7+8+9
# Output = [21,27,33,39,45,51,57,63,69,75] # till 10 times
```

> I am trying to make the sum of 0 index value to Nth index and then skip first index value(1) and start making sum from second index value(2) to Nth index value

Comment: Have you considered using a simple loop? Or are you searching for an effective solution without looping?

Comment: I am looking for an effective way

Comment: @Vipul So the expected result should be `[21, 27, 33, 39, 45, 51, 57, 63, 69, 75, 81, 87, 93, 99, 105]` ?

Comment: Yes and values in the list could be unordered sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this? -

```
n = 5 # specify the value of n
result = [sum(l[i:(i+n+1)]) for i in range(len(l)-n)][:10]
print(result)
```

Here, the idea is to evaluate the sum of 5 elements at a time and then take the top 10 elements from the list.

```
[21, 27, 33, 39, 45, 51, 57, 63, 69, 75]
```

Comment: Thankyou could you please explain it

Comment: I'm keeping a sliding window of length n while alternating over a list and then I'm evaluating the sum for each new window. Finally, I'm slicing the result to take the top 10 sum values

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need at least one loop for iterating over the list.
Below is my approach to your problem:

```
# creating a list
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in range(len(list1)):
    sm = sum(list1[i:len(list1)]) # Sum of 'a' from 0th index to 4th index. sum(a) == sum(a[0:len(a)]
    print(sm)
```